# xaxis grid not shown with twinx()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have a grid completely in the background of a plot with multiple axes. For some reason the xaxis grid is not showing up.

This is the code:

```
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
fx = 0.25* np.sin(x)**2
gx = 0.25* np.cos(x)**2


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# draw the first figure
ax1.plot(x, fx, color="g")
ax1.set_ylabel("f(x)", color="g")
ax1.grid(False)
for label in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_color("g")


# create a twin with the same x axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, gx, color="r", lw=2)
ax2.yaxis.grid(True, color="r", linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)
ax2.xaxis.grid(True, color="g", linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)
ax2.set_ylabel("g(x)", color="r")
for label in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_color("r")

ax1.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder() + 1)
ax1.set_frame_on(False)
```

And the result is this:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are drawing the gridlines, use the primary axis `ax1` instead of `ax2`. Replacing `ax2.yaxis.grid(..)` with `ax1.yaxis.grid(...)` will give you what you need... Updates lines..

```
ax1.yaxis.grid(True, color="r", linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)
ax1.xaxis.grid(True, color="g", linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)
```

...you will get this figure

[image]

Comment: But then the grid is drawn over ax2, correct? I want the grid below all charts.

Comment: If I comment out the zorder line, the lines are in front of the grid (`#ax1.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder() + 1)`)